# How to automate carousel in kivy python

Tags: python, kivy, carousel

I have a list of images as source and I want the carousel to keep displaying the images automatically by themselves without waiting for a user to push left or right.
I'm new in this please help me.
I've used while loop and for loops but nothing is working I've been stuck for past 36hrs please any help will be useful just for me to get done with this part.

Here's my code

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class CarouselApp(App):
    
    srcs = ['./images/convert1.jpg','./images/convert2.jpg','./images/convert3.jpg','./images/convert4.jpg','./images/convert5.jpg','./images/convert6.jpg']

    def build(self):
        self.carousel = Carousel(direction="right")
        for i in range(0, len(self.srcs)):
            src = self.srcs[i]
            image = Image(source=src, allow_stretch=True)
            self.carousel.add_widget(image)
        return self.carousel

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CarouselApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `load_next()` method of the `Carousel` along with `Clock.schedule_interval()`:

```
def build(self):
    self.carousel = Carousel(direction="right", loop=True)
    for i in range(0, len(self.srcs)):
        src = self.srcs[i]
        image = Image(source=src, allow_stretch=True)
        self.carousel.add_widget(image)
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.carousel.load_next, 2)
    return self.carousel
```

Comment: Oh yeah thank you it worked